# lambdaで使っているbatchwriterのエラーの原因が解りません。

Tags: aws, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-iam, aws-cloudformation

lambdaで使っているbatchwriterのエラーの原因が解りません。

前回の質問で使った以下のテンプレート
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/csv-to-dynamodb/master/CloudFormation/CSVToDynamo.template

このテンプレートで作られたs3バケットにcsvをアップすると
dynamodbに内容がインポートされるはずなのですが

どうも、s3へのアップをトリガーにしてdynamodbインポートする役割を果たす
lambdaがうまく機能していないようです。

lambdaからはエラーは見えず、cloudwatchを辿ると以下のようなエラーが出ています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

これはプログラムで用意したprint文なので
エラーが出る具体的な原因が解りません。
具体的なエラー原因を知るにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

仮説として以下が上げられます
・フォーマット表記が合わない
・ロール権限が正しく付与されていない

できればテンプレートをこのようにしたいです
・どんなファイル名でもcsv・jsonなら読めるようにする
・既存のテーブルバケットを使う

Comment: 質問したまま放置せず、解決したのであれば解決済みに、解決していないのであれば質問文を補足してください。

Comment: どうすれば解決済みに出来ますか？

Comment: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) を参考に回答を承認してください。